Mah Tovu And Shem of 42 Letters
Does anyone know a source connecting the common nusach of Mah Tovu, which has 42 words to the Shem of 42 letters?
I have searched online, Sefaria, and Otzar HaChochma without success yet.

What is "the common nusach of Mah Tovu"

Welcome to MiYodeya YSK and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

And what is  "this Shem?" I would love to be able to provide an answer but I just cannot understand the question. In any event, Welcome to Mi Yodeya, YSK.

מַה־טֹּֽבוּ אֹהָלֶֽיךָ יַעֲקֹב מִשְׁכְּ֒נֹתֶֽיךָ יִשְׂרָאֵל: וַאֲנִי בְּרֹב חַסְדְּ֒ךָ אָבוֹא בֵיתֶֽךָ אֶשְׁתַּחֲוֶה אֶל־הֵיכַל־קָדְשְׁ֒ךָ
בְּיִרְאָתֶֽךָ:  יקוק  אָהַֽבְתִּי מְעוֹן בֵּיתֶֽךָ וּמְקוֹם מִשְׁכַּן כְּבוֹדֶֽךָ: וַאֲנִי אֶשְׁתַּחֲוֶה וְאֶכְרָֽעָה אֶבְרְ֒כָה לִפְנֵי יקוק
עֹשִׂי: וַאֲנִי תְפִלָּתִי־לְךָ יְהֹוָה עֵת רָצוֹן אֱלֹהִים בְּרָב־חַסְדֶּֽךָ עֲנֵֽנִי בֶּאֱמֶת יִשְׁעֶֽךָ:

This prevalent nusash has 42 words ignoring the hyphen.  Nusach has varied.  First appears in the back of R Amram Gaon's siddur but just two pasukim there.

The Arizal in Olas tamid says the Shem of 42 has severasl forms.  I don’t have the exact Mareh Makom, but it's quoted by the Masok MiDivash on the tikkunim.  One form is the roshei of Ana Bekoach.  Another form is  אק'ה אשר אקיה.  Gematria of
אק'ה is 21.  Meshech Chochmas discusses this the Parshas Shemos by the sneh and also in Zos HaBrachah.

There are many remazim to the name in our daily routine.  The first parsh of Shema, the first bracha of Shemoneh Esrei ans Mizmor LeSoda each have 42 words.  MB 122:8 notes the Yehiyu l’Ratzon at the end of Sehmoneh Esrei has 42 words.

I’ve been working on a project in chizuk in tefillah and bitachon through understanding the significance of these remazim.    While I don’t’ have a haskama yet, several Rebbeim have reviewed parts and have agreed it’s a worhtwhile project.
I’m quite confident the Mah Tovu is a remez to this Shem based on the inyon, but I don’t a definitive source yet.

@YSK do you mean to refer to 42 letter Shem?

Yes, sorry, the Shem of 42 letters.  I see now my header was in error saying 42 words.  I fixed the header, thanks.
